# C cast syntax, how about complex casts?

Tags: c, arrays, casting

I need some help in C syntax, more about C casting syntax.
All information I found in web  is about simple casts like `(int)` or `(char)` etc...
I always get stuck in casting `void*` to a array or multi-dimentisional array or pointers of such things, but I never know how to do that!  All that I do in these cases was trying things like `(char [])` or `(char *[])` or `(*char [])` without any idea what I'm doing, until I get no errors about type casting.

Anybody have a thumb of rule to follow or some tips or tricks to do that?
For example I have a arry of void pointers and I pass it to a function, how to turn it into array again?

```
main () {
   int data1, data2;
   char data3, data4;
   void *function_data[] = {data1, data2, data3, data4};
   some_function (function_data);
   return;
}


some_function (void *data) {
   void *function_d[4];
   function_d = (void *[]) data; //It not work, how to cast data?
}
```

EDIT: I wrote wrong, I thinked that it wasn't important, so, I changed the variables data* of my code for better undestand.

Comment: You code assumes that `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, and `data4` are of type `void**`.  Is that the case?

Comment: forget about it, its assume that are of type void*, but its not important

Comment: Yes, it is important if you want to write legal working code.  If `data1` is of type `void*`, then `*data1` is illegal.  Since it's hard to tell what you're trying to do, a concrete example is even more important.

Comment: Ok sorry about that, I didnt't think that it would a really trouble.

Comment: I'm afraid your modified version is even worse.  You're trying to initialize `void*` array elements with values of type `int` and `char`; that won't even compile.  Can you show us some *real* code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to use the type definition of the intended type without the variable name and placed in parentheses as a cast to that type. For example:

```
int c;
c = (int) 4;
```

and

```
char * (*functionptr)(float, double);
functionptr = (char * (*)(float, double))myfunction;
```

Of course always assuming the type cast is possible and makes sense. Be aware: C doesn't prevent most nonsensical casts, so you'll have to take care yourself.

In your case, `function_data` is defined to be an array of pointers to void. Therefore, each data needs to be of type `void **`, as Keith already indicated.
By calling `some_function` with `function_data` as parameter, you're passing a pointer to `function_data[0]` into the function.
In order for your function to use it again as an array of 4 pointers to void, you would need to use a cast like you did, (void*[]). However, the array `function_d` is an array reserving also the space for four pointers, and you cannot change the function_d pointer (it is of type `void * * const`!). To do what you seem to want, you'll need a non-const pointer, like

```
void * * function_d = (void*[])data;
```

You may then still use it in the same way like `function_data`, using subscription like an array. `function_d[2]` will give you the value equal to `*data3`.

Comment: Greate answer, thanks a lot, but I didn't understand this part : However, the array function_d is an array reserving also the space for four pointers, and you cannot change the function_d pointer (it is of type void * * const!). To do what you seem to want, you'll need a non-const pointer, like . Can you explain I little more easy? thnaks a lot!!!

Comment: If you declare a local array variable, there's space allocated on the stack for it, and you can use the array as expected. But: You already have an array filled with data, and you're passing a pointer to that as a parameter to the function. You don't want to create a new one, but use the already existing one. Is that more clear?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `void *function_d[4];` creates new array. You cannot assign other array to it. `function_d` should be of type `void**`.

Comment: I continue getting that : error: cast specifies array type
why?

Comment: @drigoSkalWalker You need to change your cast to `void**` too.

Comment: Why I cannot assign other array to it? I learned that it is interchangeable, why I can't? Okey my code works now, but I contine without understand complex type casting...like why I had to change ( void *[]) to (void **)? and about multi dimensional arrays? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign to an array object.

How are `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, and `data4` declared?

`void*` is (or can be used as) a generic pointer type.  That can give you tremendous flexibility, but it can also inhibit type checking.

`function_data` is an array of 4 pointers to void.  In the call `some_function (function_data)`, it's implicitly converted to `void**`, a pointer to the first element.

`some_function` expects a `void*`, not a `void**` -- but any pointer type (other than a function pointer) can be implicitly converted to `void*`, so the compiler doesn't complain about the call.

Here's a version of your program that's at least type-correct (I think).

```
#include <stddef.h>

void some_function(void **data, size_t count);

int main(void) {
    void **data1, **data2, **data3, **data4;
    void *function_data[] = { *data1, *data2, *data3, *data4 };
    some_function (function_data,
                   sizeof function_data / sizeof function_data[0]);
    return 0;
}

void some_function(void **data, size_t count) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
        /*
         * do something with data[i], which is of type void*
         */
    }
}
```

Note that `data1` and friends are not initialized, so this program's behavior is undefined.  I suspect you meant to write something like:

```
void *function_data[] = { &data1, &data2, &data3, &data4 };
```

but it's hard to tell just what you're trying to do.

If you really need the function to have a *copy* of the array, you can use `memcpy()` (you can't assign array values).  For most purposes, though, it makes more sense to use pointers to access the original array.  You'll need to make a copy if you want to modify the copy without affecting the original.

And I've corrected the declarations for `main` and `some_function`, and added a declartion for `some_function` to the top so it's visible when you call it.

You should *always* explicitly declare the return type for all your functions.  In the 1990 version of C, you can omit it, and it will default to `int` (but it's still better to declare it as `int` explicitly).  In the 1999 version of C, the type is required, and you can't call a function without a visible declaration.

Again, it's hard to tell from the code you've shown us just what you're trying to do, which makes it difficult to guess how to do it.

Comment: Okey but it remains some questions, first: I can't change the declaration of the function cause it's from a library and the the prototype needs to be void *, not void **. second: I'm working only about a array of one dimesion, and about multi-dimensional array? I have to convert it to pointers like void *** (* as many dimensiosn I have)? I think that I never will use something like (char *[]) or (void *[]) that's because gcc give me the error : error: cast specifies array type. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the actual prototype of the function?  What is it supposed to do?  Is it really declared without an explicit return type?  If you're working with a multidimensional array, how exactly is it declared?  There are a number of ways to implement things that act like multidimensional arrays.  If it's a true multidimensional array (an array of arrays), you can't use a pointer-to-pointer with it.  Show us *real code*, not a summary of the pieces you think are relevant.

Comment: I can't help if you won't answer requests for clarification.  I can't read your mind.  More suggested reading: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: My question is about C complex casts, If you read the title of the question, probably should know, it's not about how declare a array in the correct way, or is right my code? it is a pseudo code, not for real use, only for example, only for people help about C COMPLEX CASTS, I think you are smart enough to hold a conversation with me. tnaks again.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

This isn't going to work:

```
int data1, data2;
char data3, data4;
void *function_data[] = {data1, data2, data3, data4};
```

because `int` and `char` are not compatible with `void *`.  You could fix this as follows:

```
void *function_data[] = {&data1, &data2, &data3, &data4};
```

because `int *` and `char *` *are* compatible with `void *`.

When you pass `function_data` to `some_function`, the array expression is converted to a pointer value, so what `some_function` receives is a `void **`.  You can use the subscript operator on the pointer as though it were an array:

```
some_function(function_data);
...
void some_function(void **data)
{
  int *x = data[0];  // remember, we stored the *addresses*
  int *y = data[1];  // of data1, data2, data3, and data4;
  char *a = data[2]; // since the type of data is void **,
  char *b = data[3]; // the type of data[i] is void *.
  ...
}
```

IOW, you don't *need* to cast `data` to an array type in order to use it like an array.